# Color of the text not working in IE8 with chrome plugin (Chrome frame)

Tags: css, colors, filter, internet-explorer-8, google-chrome-frame

The color property for the text is not working in IE8.All the other colors are working except White i.e., #fff Here is the css code used.

```
a{
text-decoration:none;
color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Any help could be appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: there is no reason at all why this wouldn't work -- that is basic CSS which should work without problems even in IE5. Can you provide a live example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: <div style="width:inherit;color:white" class="item item-header row row-item tableheader">
            <div class="col col-sep  item-text-wrap min-17 ">MY TEXT</div>
</div>

Even the color is not reflected for this code. The problem is only with the white color.